# List Item-Specific permissions

Tags: 2013, list, permissions, groups, list-item

I have a list that I would like to apply list item-specific permissions to. For example I have a list of links:

- Link 1
- Link 2
- Link 3
- Link 4

And a set of groups:

- Group 1
- Group 2
- Group 3
- Group 4

What I would like to do is apply group permissions to each list item, like so:

- Link 1 (Group 3, Group 4)
- Link 2 (Group 1)
- Link 3 (Group 2, Group 4)
- Link 4 (Group 1, Group 2, Group 4)

Is this possible without writing a script that I have to run on the server?

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a SharePoint Designer 2010 workflow (in SPD 2013) to automatically set item-level permissions when an item is created and when an item is edited.  You can use what is called a "Impersonation Step" to run the action as an administrator.

Make a column of metadata in your links list to select the "Group".  When the workflow runs, tell it to set the permissions to "Read" for the "Group" that is selected in the column.

Comment: I was hoping there was a more "out-of-the-box" solution for this. Could you give a few more details on how to set the Read permissions based on the group in the metadata column?

Comment: I think I figured out how to add the appropriate Workflow steps, but it isn't "trimming" my list items when I go to view the list.

Comment: Your workflow should go something like this, if column contains Group 1, "Replace list item permission" giving Read permission to Group 1.  Group 2, 3, and 4 should then have zero permissions.  If you are an admin, you would see all of them, but those in Group would see only the ones they got permission for.  Lots of links out there demonstrating this.

Comment: Heres a good one: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Roji.Joy/how-to-set-item-level-permission-using-sharepoint-designer-2/

Comment: Ok, so I've got the Workflow working, and verified that the list items are receiving the proper permissions. However when I go to view the list as an "unauthorized" user (i.e. not in the group assign to a list item), the list item in question is still visible. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: I managed to figure out what was going on. I had given my "unauthroized" user Full Read access to my Web Application, which effectively gave him access to everything in my list. Removed that permission, and gaving him more restrictive permissions on the site collection resulted in nice, security-trimmed list items!  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Brent.